# Introduction to the Magellanic Clouds?

Tags: galaxy, resource-request, magellanic-cloud

I'm looking for an introductory textbook on the Magellanic Clouds, something suited for a student about to obtain their Physics BS degree (ie: *no*t a professional astronomer).

I'm aware of [The Magellanic Clouds, Westerlund (1997)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997macl.book.....W), but that book is:

A) Not introductory

B) 20 years old

Are there any newer and ideally more beginner friendly textbooks out there?

Comment: Perhaps in this case, you might be better off using reputable websites for more up-to-date info and introductory stuff. Which website(s) are best, I have no clue.

Comment: Don't sell yourself short. There are thousands of journal articles about studies done in the Magellanic Clouds. Some of the info in these articles will be technical, but there will be a lot of good general information. Check this out: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#search/q=magellanic%20clouds&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc

Comment: Thank you @JackR.Woods, I'm aware that there are numerous articles published about the Magellanic Clouds. That's not what this question was about though.

Comment: I looked at the preview of the book above and it appears to be a pretty thorough covering of the subject. I think it's actually pretty current and about as introductory as you are going to find for this specific of a textbook. If the book you are looking for exists, I doubt it could be called a textbook. You are right to be looking for state of the art information, though. For example, the book above says, "The Clouds" will merge with the Milky Way. More recent evidence implies they are passing by. Easier to read, go older/ more up to date, read articles.